# How to filter out duplicated fasta sequences from a file

Tags: python, fasta

I have this code:

```
import sys
import argparse
import operator

def main (argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('infile', help='file to process')
    parser.add_argument('outfile', help='file to produce')
    args = parser.parse_args()


    with open(args.infile, "r") as f:
        with open(args.outfile,"w+") as of:
            seen=set()
            for line in f:
                line_lower = line.lower()
                if line_lower not in seen:
                    of.write(line_lower)
                else:
                    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)`
```

Example of an infile:

> M03972:51:000000000-BJVL8:1:1103:20083:5527
>   CATGTTCGGCTTGGCCTACTTCTCTATGCAGGGAGCGTGGGCGAGAGTCGTTGTCATCCTTCTGCTGGCCGCCGGGGTGGACGCGCGCACCCATACTGTTGGGGGTTCTGCCGCGCAGACCACCGGGCGCCTCACCAGCTTATTTGACATGGGCCCCAGGCAGAAAATCCAGCTCGTTAACACCAATGGCAGCTGGCACATCAACCGCACCGCCCTGAACTGCAATGACTCCTTGCACACCGGCTTTATCG

Sometimes there are duplicated sequences. I would like to remove them but I my code doesn't seem to work. It just duplicates the file basically but doesnt throw any error. 
Does anyone know why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add lines that were unique to `seen`. Here's the fixed portion of the code:

```
seen=set()
for line in f:
    line_lower = line.lower()
    if line_lower not in seen:
        of.write(line_lower)
    else:
        seen.add(line_lower)
```